# Django change color of the tab in chrome

Tags: django

I ahve an app that monitors a few processes and alerts if some are failing. It does so by changing the background color of the body. However, due to lack of screen real estate the browser is often covered and I only have the top part visible, showing the tabs and maybe the address bar. So, I thought it would be neat if I could change the tab color as an alert.
Chrome has the tabs above the address bar

[image: Tabs in chrome]

I can modify the title of the head...

```
<head class="{{mode}}">
    <title>ProcessMonitor</title>
</head>
```

but changing the background color here doesnt seem to do anything

```
head.alert {
    background-color: #FFD6C6;
    font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
```

Is it possible to change the color of that tab somehow or does chrome just not support that?

Comment: It's not possible to do it using js or css, only by installing browser extension. And nothing to do with django in your question

Comment: Ok, thanks.It would have to work on the standard browser just with the usual tools, like css, js. So feel free to post that as an answer and I ll accept it in a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do it using js or css, only by installing browser extension